# How do I format an HDD to GPT partition style using Windows 10's installation disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I'm trying to install Windows 10 in GPT mode, but unfortunately the disk inside the computer I'm trying to install into is already formatted using MBR.

I've been working around this problem by first booting into Linux using my thumb drive, formatting the disk as GPT, rewriting the same thumb drive with the Windows image, and then finally installing Windows 10. This is time-consuming and not good for my thumb drive's health.

Can I format from within the Windows installer?

Please note that I'm *not* looking to convert MBR to GPT with the data intact, so `MBR2GPT` is not an answer.

Comment: You need re-partition, not re-format. Start installation, remove all partitions (including hidden, reserved, unknown type, etc.) from HDD, and restart installation - it must ask what style (MBR or GPT) you want to use...

Comment: @Akina So, I simply need to erase all existing partitions, and then restart?

Comment: To avoid having to rewrite the thumb drive with different images, get a second thumb drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to open a Cmd window.
2. Run `diskpart`.
3. Use `list disk` and `sel[ect] disk <num>` to choose the physical disk.
4. Use `clean` to delete all partitions.
5. Use `convert gpt` to create a blank GPT partition table.

Recently this has been added to the official [Microsoft documentation site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style).